# Background Change on Scroll is flickering

Tags: jquery, background-image

I tried to get the "background image change on scroll" working on my page.
but while scrolling the changes are flickering. I couldn't find a solution in other threads.

This is what I have:

jquery:

```
$(function(){
$(document).scroll(function () {


    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('body').css({
            backgroundImage: 'url("img/picture1.jpg")'
        });
    }


      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 800) {
        $('body').css({
            backgroundImage: 'url("img/picture2.jpg")'
        });
    }
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url('../img/picture1.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show a live version or a http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: You are constantly setting the background image, over and over again.  You need to store the state in a variable, so ou only set the background once you first pass the 800px mark etc.

Comment: thank you, but can you explain this a bit more precise. Im new to jquery... :/

Answer (score 0):

The flickering is probably due to the second image loading. You can preload the second image using javascript's native `Image` object:

```
var newImg = new Image();
newImg.src = 'img/picture2.jpg';
```

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VjmfY/).

Comment: Thanks this works! 
But how can i go for more pictures? This wont work:
http://jsfiddle.net/VjmfY/2/

Comment: You can create a function and pass all the images as arguments for preloading: [jsfiddle.net/VjmfY/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/VjmfY/3/)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure when you want to change the background-image, but if you want to preload and change it consistently like per 800 scroll increment. I made a solution that might help you, [**jsfiddle.net/VjmfY/4/**](http://jsfiddle.net/VjmfY/4/).

Comment: thank you..the images should change on different pixel values, like 800, 1200, 1800...